# How to call a web page from android without exiting the app

Tags: android, web

I'm new in Android i need call web page from my app without exiting I try with this code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.google.es"));
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

and doesn't work.

Thank for the help!!!

Comment: If you want to bring them to the browser: activity.startActivityForResult(intent), if within the activity, use WebView.

Comment: Use [WebView](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)

Answer (score 1):

In your xml layout file, use a WebView

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to display a web page from within your app, you will need to create a webview.

[Here is good tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)